# error in sharepoint designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am getting error in sharepoint designer workflow.
Error is :The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information - access denied

This error always occurs when user with contribute access add item.
Error does not occurs when user with admin access add.

How to solve this. I cannot elevate access from contribute to admin.

I have used "set field in current item" 2 place

Comment: pause in workflow is now working

Comment: *pause in workflow is not working

Comment: Verify that a column is getting the wrong kind of information. For example, a column of numbers getting a string.

Comment: Two fields I am updating.
1.set value from dropdown selection to single line of text
2.set value from single line of text to another single line of text.

Comment: Are you using worflows 2013? Or 2010?

Comment: sharepoint designer 2010

Comment: I have added pause for duration action at correct place and now it is working. But is there any other option to overcome this?

Comment: I'm sorry, i dont know with hep you. In wokflows 2013 permission of ad group not work. But in 2010 all work. :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case ,problem is occured due to no of columns in list are high.Please delete unused columns in list(specially people picker columns).

Comment: Welcome to community. You should not post comments or questions in this section. This section is meant for solution/answer to problem. You can wait till you get commenting rights to comment